# What is the best solutions to code this view?

Tags: drupal

I'm coding new website powered by drupal 8. I need to code page with sidebar (category list) and post / posts view.
What is the best solution to do that?

Comment: This question is way to vague and would probably depend on too many factors specific to your site. The views module is probably what you want, but there is no way of us knowing without many more details. Look for some tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

Use views module.

Make side bar region in your theme and create block view that will list categories. Add that block to side bar region.

Also make page view which will list posts. You can even add exposed filters so your posts page can have them.

And for detailed post view use just default node page. You can create custom node templates for your content (node) type so you can style that page as you like. Same goes for view page / block. Find original template, name it's copy by following naming convention so it will be used just for your node type / view page / view block and adjust html to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

user Better Expose Filter Because The Better Exposed Filters module replaces the Views' default single- or multi-select boxes with radio buttons or checkboxes, respectively Easy to Filter To Category